# conflict between macro defined tcl-8.5.12 and method in qt-4.7.4

Tags: c++, qt, tcl, build-process

I am porting our product from tcl-8.4 to tcl-8.5.12

in new version of tcl there is a macro defined in tclInt.h

```
#define localName(framePtr, i) \
    ((&((framePtr)->localCachePtr->varName0))[(i)])
```

also my product uses Qt-4.7.4. And in qt-4.7.4/include/QtXml/qdom.h there is attribute

```
QString localName() const;
```

As a result I am getting error: qt-4.7.4/include/QtXml/qdom.h:165:23: error: macro "localName" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given

Any suggestions to resolve this imbroglio?

Going to undef macro in tcl. Will see what happens, although, even if it fixes the situation I don't much like that solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to include tclInt.h at all? Its an internal header usually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would using a inline function definition in qt/c++ code help?

```
inline vartype localName(int* framePtr, int i){
  return framePtr->localCachePtr->varName0.at(i);
}
```

Since it is possible to have more functions of same name but different parameters(count) this should call the correct function and being inline this will replaced at compile time.

Edit: Mhh, i just saw your problem is probably the inverse? You cannot compile because localName(Something) always calls the macro. You definitly will have to remove the macro, but using it as inline function call will hopefully solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The normal solution here would be to have a wrapper class for
the tcl stuff.  The only include of any tcl headers would be in
the implementation of the wrapper class, and that wouldn't
include anything from Qt.